# $Z_2$ action yields decomposition into a direct sum

Tags: group-actions, c-star-algebras, graded-algebras

If I have a $Z_2$ (group with two elements) action on a $C^*$-algebra $A$, i.e. $A$ is graded by the definition of Ralf Meyer for example, then how may I decompose $A$ into a direct sum $A_0\oplus A_1$ such that I get the definition of a graded $C^*$-algebra of Blackadar for example.

The reason for this question is that with the definition of a $Z_2$ action I wonder how to declare the degree of an element, in particular how to define graded commutator.

Comment: Could you maybe add the relevant definitions so that your question becomes self-contained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sigma$ is the automorphism corresponding to the nontrivial group element, then
$$A_0=\{a\in A:\sigma(a)=a\}$$
and
$$A_1=\{a\in A:\sigma(a)=-a\}.$$

Comment: But why is this a decomposition of $A$, i.e. why does $A\cong A_0\oplus A_1$ hold?

Comment: $$a=(a+\sigma(a))/2+(a-\sigma(a))/2$$